# How to concatenate a column value based on another column value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, ms-office

I have sheet like this :

[image: Image 1]

How can I concatenate values in `column B` based on value in `column A`.

Values corresponding to ID `1.1.1` are of `B2:B5`
Similarly, values for ID `1.1.2` are of `B6:B8` and so on..
Its like it start from first id, lookup until next id, all values in `column B` until next Id in `column A` is concatenated

the result should be like this : `2,3,4,5` in single cell of `column D`

Comment: Could not get your question, what do you want to do? do you want values of column b where column A is emtpy?

Comment: yes i need like that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would solve your purpose, but you can keep concatenating values till the value in column A is same and use the last value.

Assuming the case you provided, paste the formula `=IF(A2<>"",B2,D1&", "&B2)` in cell `D2` and copy throughout the column. You can additionally create a flag for changes in column E using `=IF(A2<>"",1,"")` in cell `E2`. The results would be like this.

[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 0):

It's still not quite clear, what you are trying to achieve, but to simply concatenate columns with a comma as separator, you can try something like the following:

In column d2 (or column d5), type in the following formula

```
=B2&","&B3&","&B4&","&B5
```

That should get you in the right direction.